# Configuring OSGI Services on a per use basis

Tags: java, osgi

I want to create a paging service that will return pages based on a SQL like query.  Here is the simple interface:

```
public interface IPage {
  public boolean hasNext();
  public Object[] next();
}
```

When I call this service I want to be able to initialize it with a query String and a page size int.

How do I go about getting a reference to the service that has been initialized with the arguments specified above?  I would prefer to use declarative services but it seems to me I would have to use ServiceTracker if I wanted to pass in arguments.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead exposing IPage as a service, you might expose an IPageFactory as a service instead. The factory would then take a query and a page size, and return an initialised IPage instance.